# Ubuntu 13.10 on Acer C720

Tags: 13.10, chromebook

Does anyone know how to do a clean install of Ubuntu on this chromebook? By this I mean that I want to totally remove ChromeOS and only use Ubuntu, I don't want to use Crubuntu. Just a link to a guide would be fine, thanks! :)

Comment: See http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=acer_c720_linux&num=1 and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_C720_Chromebook

Answer (score 5):

Install via jeltka, following [these instructions](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/).

This flashes the bios.  After rebooting, you will have two choices - choose the second.  Then type `root`.   This gives you a root shell. Once you have a prompt, run the script `jeltka.sh`.

Presently it all works - except the touchpad, so I am using a usb mouse. I am trying to figure out how to make the touchpad work.